# NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I am trying to follow the tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

And I have some idea as to what's happening, but at this point I am becoming exponentially more upset and unequipped to look at this in a way that makes sense.here is my controller currently. it's very simple and I thought I knew what was going on:

```
articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  @article.save
  redirect_to @article
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resource :articles
root 'welcome#index'
    end
end
```

But I am now out of my depth and can no longer proceed. If it makes a difference I am running windows 8 pro. Any help would be appreciated. I can tell the error has something to do with 'redirect_to' but I don't know anything outside of that!
My error now looks like:

```
NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create
undefined method `article_url' for #<ArticlesController:0x979bfc0>
Extracted source (around line #0):

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

And the stack trace looks like this:

```
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:268:in `handle_model_call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:167:in `url_for'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:95:in `_compute_redirect_to_location'
turbolinks (2.5.3) lib/turbolinks/xhr_headers.rb:21:in `_compute_redirect_to_location'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:75:in `redirect_to'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:57:in `redirect_to'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:61:in `block in redirect_to'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:60:in `redirect_to'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:9:in `create'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
```

Comment: please add your routes to the question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically the "undefined method `article_url' for " means that rails can't find an appropriate route for the @article record. When defining a route, rails generates two methods ending in _url and _path. You can use them in your application to access the respective urls without hardcoding them. Looking at the code in your routes.rb file, I have found three things:

1. You only need one call to Rails.application.routes.draw
2. The key word for generating the CRUD routes for a model is "resources" (plural), not "resource" (singular)
3. (Not concerning the error) Your "get 'welcome/index'" looks not finished. Maybe you meant something line "get '/index', to: 'welcome#index'". The first string specifies the url path, the to specifies the controller#action.

Try with the following routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

I recommend that you also go through the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) while you are at it. Good luck!

Comment: The routing guide is very helpful, This is the first time I've meddled with any kind of web app software like this so the errors aren't vey descriptive to me at this point. 'resources' was the current problem, it's nice to know 1 and 3 though.

Comment: I am glad that this was of help to you! Rails is really nice framework and the Ruby is a really fun and interesting language. I hope you have a lot of fun while using them both! :)

Comment: +1 for item #2. It's an easy thing to overlook, but my problem was that I wrote `resource` instead of the plural `resources`. My hint should have been when the guide says the route for `show` is `article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show` including the `:id`. When I reviewed `bin/rake routes` again, my show route did not have the `:id` param specified.

Comment: @ctlockey I might have done the same mistake 3 years later hahaha.

Answer (score 7):

Ah you see, the problem is that you used the singular `resource` word, not the `resources` (note the `s`), in your case you should be using `resources`, because you have multiple articles

More about [resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web), and [resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Comment: 'resources' was definitely the current problem and I am now back on track with this tutorial! I'm sure there's plenty of other problems with what I have so far but at least now I can at least continue to muddle through the tutorial, thank you!

Comment: glad you fixed your problem, if there's nothing else then please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: That is right, I made the same mistake. That is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to the `@article` show page after creating `article` but you don't have this method defined in your `ArticlesController`. You have to define that method and create a view for it. Also, what are your routes?

Comment: actually the problem is probably that the route isn't defined, or he's excluding the show route

Comment: Can you show me how you define a route for that action? And also - do you have a show view for Article?

Comment: at this point I think I'm supposed to be getting an error for 'show', but I can't quite get that far

Answer (score 0):

This is one hard code that implement resource work 
You can pass json object to redirect_to

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to articles_path({:id => @article.id})
   end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```